# JSNI dynamic function reference in GWT

Tags: gwt, jsni

I would like to call arbitrary js function from gwt. Function name would be inside functionname variable. Something like this:

```
private static native String execute(String functionName, JavaScriptObject data) /*-{
    return $wnd.functionName(data);
}-*/;
```

I assume that something like this could be possible, but how to create fn variable to represent my arbitrary functionname function.

```
private static native String execute(JavaScriptObject fn, JavaScriptObject data) /*-{
    return fn(data);
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to invoke function by name, you need to do something like this:

```
private static native String execute(String functionName,JavaScriptObject data)/*-{
     $wnd[functionName](data);

}-*/;
```

To get reference to a function you will need to use JSNI like this:

```
private static native JavaScriptObject getFunction(String functionName)/*-{
    return  $wnd[functionName];

}-*/;
```

Comment: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Property 'my.function.name' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Btw, direct call works, so js function exists:

private static native String execute(String functionName, JavaScriptObject data) /*-{
    return $wnd.my.function.name(data);
}-*/;

Comment: You are using invalid path. Function name should'nt contain any dots. Otherwise you will have to use something like $wnd["my"]["function"]["name"]();

Comment: @Matija basically it is totally valid error, because $wnd onject doesn't have any function named "my.function.name". It contains only object my, which contains object function, which contains function name.

Comment: Thank you. This has solved my problem. Dots in function name are result of namespaces in google closure template concept.